# jqXHR.responseText returns no detailed validation info?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

It appears I cannot make the validation work.

All I have is a `500 Internal Server Error`. And my `responseText` is `"{"Message":"An error has occurred."}"`.

But shouldn't it be a 400 error and contain something more detailed?

Here is my model:

```
public class InjuryNoAnnotationModel
{
    public int OutfitterId { get; set; }
    public string OutfitterName { get; set; }
    public string LicenseNumber { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime InjuryDate { get; set; }
    public int InjuryHour { get; set; }
    public int InjuryMinute { get; set; }
}
```

my json:

```
var data = {
            "OutfitterId": "11",
            "OutfitterName": "WVDNR -- For Testing",
            "LicenseNumber": "sss",
            "InjuryDate": "08/16/2013",
            "InjuryHour": "sss",
            "InjuryMinute": "0"
        };
```

if the `InjuryHour` is a number, the model binding will work. The breakpoint in my controller can be reached. The success callback in `.done()` is reached.

But if I changed the `InjuryHour` into a text, it throws a 500 instead of 400. My controller breakpoint is never reached. The fail callback in `.fail()` is reached.

Comment: A 500 error doesn't mean validation failed, it means there was an unhandled exception on the server. Debug your server code.

Comment: Looks like the problem is not with the validation, but an actual run-time error. If you use the developer tools and click on the 'Network' tab, you should be able to see the error.

Comment: I assume you are debugging using Chrome. But where should I look into in the `Network` tab?

Answer (score 0):

if `InjuryHour` is a String,it can't auto convert and match to param `InjuryNoAnnotationModel`.example,the Action defined: `public ActionResult DoSomething(InjuryNoAnnotationModel model)`,then the request would be not match it.In fact,the Route will find Action named `DoSomething(int OutfitterId,string OutfitterName....**string InjuryHour**,int InjuryMinute)`.So,server response 500 error:Not implement.
InjuryHour convert to string is right.The breakpoint is not working must be some other reason,can you show the Action code?